# Редактирование нескольких ячеек Contenteditable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Имеется таблица с 4 столбцами. У ячеек таблицы установлен атрибут contenteditable. Вся информация выводится с БД.

```
<?php foreach($options as $option):?>
  <tr>
      <td><?=$option['id']?></td>
      <td><?=$option['title']?></td>
      <td class="name" contenteditable><?=$option['name']?></td>
      <td class="type" data-id ="<?=$option['id']?>" contenteditable>
<?=$option['type']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Нужно сделать так что бы редактируемая информация в ячейках сохранялась в БД. Мне удалось реализовать сохранение ячеек только последнего столбца. Параметр data-id я передаю в файл script.js.

```
    $('.type').focus(function(){
        oldVal = $(this).text();
        id = $(this).data('id');
    }).blur(function(){
    newVal = $(this).text();
    if(newVal != oldVal){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {new_val: newVal, id: id},
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

С помощью Ajax эти значения отправляются в файл index.php, откуда они добавляются в базу:

```
function update_option(){
    global $db;
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['new_val']);
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE options SET type = '$type' WHERE id = $id";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if( mysqli_affected_rows($db) ) return true;
        else return false;
}
```

Но это только для полей одного столбца. А как сделать для тоже самое только для поля "name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
<?php foreach($options as $option):?>
  <tr>
      <td><?=$option['id']?></td>
      <td><?=$option['title']?></td>
      <td class="name" contenteditable data-id ="<?=$option['id']?>"><?=$option['name']?></td>
      <td class="type" contenteditable data-id ="<?=$option['id']?>"><?=$option['type']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

JS:

```
$('.type, .name').focus(function() {
        oldVal      = $(this).text();
        id          = $(this).data('id');
        thisClass   = $(this).attr('class'); 

    }).blur(function() {
    newVal = $(this).text();

    if(newVal != oldVal)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {new_val: newVal, id: id, thisClass: thisClass},
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
function update_option(){
    global $db;
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['new_val']);
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];

    if($_POST['thisClass'] == 'name')
    {
        $query = "UPDATE options SET name = '".$type."' WHERE id = ".$id;
    }
    else if($_POST['thisClass'] == 'type')
    {
        $query = "UPDATE options SET type = '".$type."' WHERE id = ".$id;
    }


    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if( mysqli_affected_rows($db) ) return true;
        else return false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! Все получилось)))